# Make Spring accept UTF-8 Characers in rest calls

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, encoding

I build a small Spring-Boot application and have a problem with utf-8 encoded character.
In my controller I have a method like

```
@DeleteMapping("deleteIngredient/{ingredientId}")
public void delteIngredient(@PathVariable final String ingredientId) {
    ingredientService.delteIngredient(ingredientId);
}
```

But calling `localhost:8080/deleteIngredient/käse`results in

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:475) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:294) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_221]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_221]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: works with "localhost:8080/deleteIngredient/k%C3%A4se"?

Comment: Yes it does. But I don't want to do that every time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java utf8 encoding - char, string types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187645/java-utf8-encoding-char-string-types)

Comment: @VinayPrajapati no, not really.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicode characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring is complaining about german Umlauts here, "ä" is not allowed.

> The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986

The same reason you cannot have a domain like "[dasörtliche.de](https://www.dasoertliche.de/)".

You probably could force spring to accept Umlauts, but you would violate the RFC. My advice is to encode the links your api produces to be conform with the RFC (probably already springs default). A client then would need to encode `käse` to `k%C3%A4se` itself (if it is constructing a link itself and not using your links that are conform to RFCs), but any client should be accustomed to that already.

Comment: Ok I see. So basically I shouldn't force that. Thank you :D